# my program works fine on the emulator but crashes on the phone

Tags: java, android

i making a project that encrypts text and then share it on social platform it works fine on the emulator  but when i run it on phone and try to do the desired function it crashes and gives me this exception
gjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/Base64;
this is the class for encryption and decryption
public class AES {

```
    private SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public AES(String secret, int length, String algorithm)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        byte[] key ;
        key = fixSecret(secret, length);
        this.secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm);
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    }

    private byte[] fixSecret(String s, int length) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (s.length() < length) {
            int missingLength = length - s.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < missingLength; i++) {
                s += " ";
            }
        }
        return s.substring(0, length).getBytes("UTF-8");
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public String encryptFile(String f)
            throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(f));
        this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
        byte[] output = this.cipher.doFinal(f.getBytes());

        Log.e("output", String.valueOf(output));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public String decryptFile(String f)
            throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Log.e("f", String.valueOf(f));
        this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
        byte[] decordedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(f);
        byte[] output = this.cipher.doFinal(decordedValue);
        Log.e("output", String.valueOf(output));
        String decryptedString = new String(output);
        Log.e("decryptedString",decryptedString);
        return decryptedString;
    }

}
```

and this is where i encrypt and then send it through social platform

```
public void cipherOptionDialog(){
         enter code herecipherOptionMenu = new Dialog(createNewMessage.this);
         cipherOptionMenu.setContentView(R.layout.cipher_option_dialog_box);
         optionAes = cipherOptionMenu.findViewById(R.id.option_aes);
         optionDes = cipherOptionMenu.findViewById(R.id.option_des);
         optionAes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {


                 String plainText = enterMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                 try {
                     encryptedText = inputAES.encryptFile(plainText);
                 } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 socialMediaOptionDialog();
             }

         });
        cipherOptionMenu.show();
    }
```

please help